# Sencha Touch - Displaying a webpage in a panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, embedding

I have an app with tabs across the bottom. When a tab is selected I would like to display an external webpage in the app, for example Google.

Upon searching found some stuff for calling with AJAX and some iframe stuff. Is there really no way to just embed the external webpage into the panel? Am I missing something?

Comment: Since Sencha itself produces HTML, I don't think that there is any method that is more convenient than those suggested. What type of embedding methods did you have in mind that would be easier? On a side note, some websites have "anti-embedding" code that would make them take control over the browser window, so embedding an arbitrary web page within another is far from being trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more elegant ways to do this, and its a little hard working out which would be best as there isn't much detail regarding your set-up and what you're after.

A simple way would be to simply intercept the click event of the tab and then change the panel's html to whatever you so desire, e.g.

```
listeners:{
 click:function(){
    myPanel.html="<iframe src='http://www.google.com'></iframe>";
 }
}
```

You could also include a check for which tab is being clicked then change the called URL as a result...